# Send a message to a view controller using -tabBarController:didSelectViewController?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to send a message to a UITableViewController that is attached to a TabBarController, and has a naviagation bar. However, I'm not sure what to do to send the message. Currently (for testing purposes), I have:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog( @"Selected tabbar");
    [viewController sendMessage];
}
```

NSLog fires off fine before the code fails on the next line with "unrecognized selector sent to instance...", which tells me I'm close, but I'm sending -sendMessage to the wrong object. What am a looking for to send -sendMessage to the UITableViewController instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewController has an array called viewControllers. In my case there is only one object in the array; It's just a guess, but I think objectAtIndex:0 is the topmost view controller.

Here's the code I was looking for:

```
activeViewController = [[viewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

It's a little off topic, but with this level of control, you can store the last active view controller, so that when you navigate away from a tab, you can send it any message you want; even ask it if it should stay active.

Comment: Hmm.. I think this is probably wrong. The UIViewController object that was selected is the one pointed to by the pointer 'viewController'. There is no involved here array. I think the problem is that the object that was pointed to doesn't respond to '@selector(sendMessage)'

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `UITableViewController` instance has a method called `-sendMessage`. Remember that this will be called for every selection, so do *all* of your view controllers respond to `-sendMessage`? It seems surprising that you would want to send this in all cases. Perhaps you meant to include a line like:

```
if (viewController == self.tableViewController)
```

You can learn a lot about what's going on by adding something like this:

```
NSLog(@"Selected viewController: %@", viewController);
```

Then you'll know what object you're talking to (at least what class).

Comment: I did check into that at one point, but all I can get out of it is <UINavigationController: 0xf47040>. I'm not sure how to use that to send a message to my UITableViewController. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your UITableView appears to be nested inside of a UINavigationController, which is the view that is actually being selected by the tab bar controller. Why not just have your UITableViewController implement -viewDidAppear if there are things you want to perform when it appears?

Comment: Because it's too easy ;) Seriously though, this was the first step in a larger problem, the larger problem being to notify a view controller when a different tab was selected (not when the view is dismissed).